# Python 3.6 - Detecting what tabs are open in internet browsers

Tags: python, web, tracker

I want to make a program in python that can keep track of what tabs the user has open in their browser (Chrome, IE and Microsoft Edge, but preferably all browsers), however, after doing a bit of research I have been unable to find any modules that will enable this. Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as a module goes?

For anyone wondering I want to keep track of the time spent running this tab, so the user can see what programs they have run throughout the day. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a single module that does that. You will have to create/use for each browser. Futhermore it will likely be operating system specific.

For example for Chrome (or any other browser) on OSX you will like you the [AppleScript interface](http://www.mugginsoft.com/html/kosmictask/ASDictionaryDocs/Google/Google-Chrome/OS-X-10.7/Google-Chrome-19.0.1084.56/html/) [wrapping it around](http://juanreyero.com/article/python/os-x-python.html) Python or using  [MacPython OSA](https://www.afpy.org/doc/python/2.7/library/macosa.html)

I am not familiar with Linux or Windows, but I bet there should be a similar way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I unfortunately use Windows, however I will look at these links and see if there is an equivalent.